# Twitter Bootstrap 2: Navbar submenu links do not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

After updating to Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 (which is awesome), the navigation links **inside** submenus do not work.

jQuery is at 1.7.1. The Dropdowns actually work, and the markup is correct (according to the docs):

```
<!-- start navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">

    <!-- start navbar-inner -->
    <div class="navbar-inner">

        <!-- start container-fluid -->
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <?php echo anchor('home', 'SCAA', array('class' => 'brand')); ?>

            <ul class="nav">

                <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <?php echo anchor('#', 'Inscripciones <span class="caret"></span>', array('class' => 'dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown')); ?>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><?php echo anchor('inscriptions/add', 'Nueva Inscripción'); ?></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><?php echo anchor('inscriptions', 'Mostrar Todas'); ?></li>
                        </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end nav -->

        </div>
        <!-- end container-fluid -->

    </div>
    <!-- end navbar-inner -->

</div>
<!-- end navbar -->
```

**Note:** I'm using Codeigniter to generate the links, but with plain  tags isn't working either.

The plugins are being loaded correctly.

I'm calling the dropdowns with `jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`

I don't know what else to do or check. Any hints?

Comment: Have you downloaded and loaded bootstrap.js? Normally, I don't think that you have to explicitly call jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(). Simply placing the data-toggle="dropdown" (as you already have) should be sufficient

Comment: The JavaScript wasn't the problem. With further analysis, I noticed that `data-toggle="dropdown"` was messing around with the links, __because it was being declared in the <li> element, too__. `data-toggle="dropdown"` should only be declared inside the `<a>` tag right after `<li class="dropdown">`.

Comment: in this case, since you found it, you can answer your own question and mark it as completed

Comment: Didn't knew that one, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The markup is not correct (at least, not entirely) - the problem was the declaration of data-toggle="dropdown" inside the containing `<li>` element. It should be in the 1st child  of that list element.

To make it work, simple delete the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute from the list element and it'll be done.