# Bootstrap Dropdown won't expand on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar from bootstrap and one of the menus is a dropdown that allows me to select a course.

The first pic is what it looks like on my desktop when I click on courses, working perfectly fine.

[image: desktop]

When I try to select it on mobile, nothing happens.

This is the navbar code
[image: code]

And the scripts I include. 
[image: js]
[image: css]

Any insight on this issue would be much appreciated

Comment: Please post the code instead of using images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here yo go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/rskte8s5/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Course <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Accounting & Information System</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aerospace Engineering</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Business Information Technology</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computer Science</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Electrical & Computer Engineering</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Math</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link, I think you might find something that will work for you.

[Drop-Down Menu not working on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579750/drop-down-menu-not-working-on-mobile-devices)