# Bootstrap 3: Mobile nav opens on desktop, but not on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a website for a couple of friends and am nearing the finish of it:

http://hopetherapy.info

Challenge:
When I click on the mobile nav hamburger menu, it opens on a desktop (make the window skinny to test) in FireFox, Safari, Chrome on a Mac so far. On an iPhone 6 OS 10.1.1 though, choosing the hamburger menu results in no action (haven't tested on Android yet).

I did rearrange the menu for this design to be right-aligned and merged with another WordPress theme which may have caused some issue I'm not seeing yet.

Resulting menu HTML:

```
<header id="nav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">
    <div class="container">

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img alt="Hope Heals Counseling" src="/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-hope-heals/img/hope-heals-counseling2.png"></a>

      <a class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav pull-right navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-27 active active"><a href="http://hopetherapy.info/">Home</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="http://hopetherapy.info/answers/">Answers</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="http://hopetherapy.info/blog/">Blog</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="http://hopetherapy.info/contact/">Contact</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-28"><a href="tel:16164227787">Call: +1.616.422.7787</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>  

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the hamburger menu not to open on iPhone?

Comment: Could you please post your meta tags?

Comment: Of course. Here is full template link: http://christopherstevens.cc/hopeheals/web2d/ It turns out that my original design template, prior to merging into WordPress, is having the same issue. Linked simpler code may help troubleshoot quicker.

Comment: Hm, viewport meta tag is there.  Your site also works on Android Note 6 just fine. I recently learned of an error that the iPhone 5 had in some circumstances: When there was opacity applied to something it would not show up. I don't know if that might be the cause. 
What shows up instead? Does the normal nav stay on screen?

Comment: Thanks for the note and Android test @Falk. On my iPhone, nothing happens when I press the hamburger menu icon. The button itself doesn't even change color as if the menu icon/link selection itself is not possible. It's static. Let me play with opacity next....

Comment: Another idea would be the update your jQuery and make sure it is imported. The console log error seems like something that would happen when JS doesn't understand that $ stands for jQuery. Since Bootstrap requires jQuery that might tie in to the issue (and at the same time if that would be it, you should see the problem on all mobile devices). Another thing you could do is: head over to the Apple forums and ask there. Since this seems oddly version specific, they might have a better idea.

Comment: Good thoughts. I need to leave this task for a short while (been staring at it too long). I'll take a fresh look soon today and experiment. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Someone already answered this question for me, discovered after a fresh search. I was missing the href="#" on the hamburger menu. [Full details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960405/bootstrap-3-dropdown-on-ipad-not-working).

Answer (score -2):

it looks like there's a console error that may be affecting the javascript. this is the code that's generating the error:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     //scroll to next section on home page
    $("#goscroll").click(function(e) { 
     var offset = 50;
     e.preventDefault(); 
     var dest = $("#services");

       $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: window.innerHeight - offset }, 2500); 
      });

});
```

The error says that $ is undefined. to define $ change this line

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

To this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

That should clear the error then check and see if the nav works after that.

Comment: Let me check it out (and I didn't -1 you, thanks for the comment)

Comment: I tried out your solution which can be tested out at http://www.christopherstevens.cc/hopeheals/web2d2 , no dice this time.