# bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown not working on IOS devices / safari

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, safari, navbar

I just uploaded a new bootstrap-site a couple of days ago. Since then I had reported, that the navbar does not work on IOS devices. The problem does not occur on any other device or browser, just Safari.

When clicking/touching the hamburger symbol, the dropdown does open properly, but when clicking the submenu-dropdown the whole navbar collapses without showing the submenu. So therefore the submenu is not accessible at all - which basically makes the whole site inaccessible on IOS.

Does anyone know a solution?
Thanks

here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid pb-2">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-alert fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand pr-4" href="../index.html">Naturpark Weissensee</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown"> 
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Unterkunft buchen
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Hotels.html">Hotels</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Pensionen.html">Pensionen</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Camping.html">Camping</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Ferienwohnungen.html">Ferienwohnungen</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Weissensee%20Umgebung.html">Weissensee Umgebung</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Sommer
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Wasser.html">... am See</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Dorf.html">... im Dorf</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Wald.html">... im Wald</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Schifffahrt.html">Schiffrundfahrt</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Winter
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown3">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Schnee.html">... im Schnee</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Eissport.html">... am Eis</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Information
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown4">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Wissenswertes.html">Wissenswertes</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Anlaufstellen.html">Anlaufstellen</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. Navbar dropdowns work on most browsers, but not iOS with Safari. Did you find out what the issue was?

Comment: I am having same issue.
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse {
display: -ms-flexbox !important;
}
display: inline-block and flexbox are not working. This is the main issue. Haven't found any solutions yet.

Answer (score 6):

Holy crap I found the problem it is sheer madness. The dropdown menus need an href=# (like...literally a # in my code, not an actual address). So for instance:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Unterkunft buchen
</a>
```

This is one of the most insidious bugs I've ever had to track down! I found the answer at stack overflow:
[Bootstrap 3 Dropdown on iPad not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960405/bootstrap-3-dropdown-on-ipad-not-working/20963048#20963048)

Comment: Holly crap indeed! Thanks for figuring it out. Saved me a ton of time from tracking down something so nonsensical. I wish Safari would just die already. It's the new IE6.

Comment: @Asif Raza but the issue is Navbar of Bootstrap 4 is not showing on iOS devices and on Safari Browser

Answer (score 1):

**Safari issue with navbar dropdown menu failing to show when using `position:fixed`**

I got a similar issue in Safari (on laptop) where no navbar dropdown menus would show when I used `position: fixed` for the top element (the navbar). It would solve when I used `position: sticky`, but that gave other (styling) issues.

I'm talking about an example for plain JavaScript from w3schools.com, which can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar).
I adapted this example to be able to get a navbar which shows & hides depending on the scrolling behavior. So, among other things, I added a `position: fixed` to the CSS.

The solution was to set the **overflow** property of the navbar to **visible** (instead of **hidden** as it was done in the example on w3schools.com, which by the way works also for Safari as it doesn't use any scrolling-dependent behavior). This somehow did the trick, and also still works in Firefox and the Chromium-based Brave browser, so probably also in Chrome.

Here's the CSS code that works also for Safari:

```
.navbar {
  overflow: visible; /* Solution for the Safari issue with navbar dropdown menu failing to show:
  Simply setting this overflow CSS property of the navbar to visible instead of hidden. */
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Safari issue with navbar dropdown menu failing to show up front:
  Issue: Only if position:sticky the dropdown menu works in Safari,
  but then the navbar stops working as desired, with showing/hiding dependent on scrolling. */
  top: 0; /* Was -50px; in the example, but that's irrelevant for the Safari issue. */
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
}
```