# Why would this nav not show on iPhone 13 Safari?

Tags: html, iphone, bootstrap-4, safari

I have a website that has a `<nav>` element at the top where it shows main menu links and a number of other things.

For years it worked just fine across all devices ever tested against (even Microsoft) just not on iPhone 13.

```
<header class="wrapper header">
  <nav class="navbar top navbar-top navbar-expand-lg d-print-none navbar-primary bg-primary text-white fixed-top ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/?ref=top_brand_logo">MyWebsite</a>
    <div class="mobile-navbar-items d-sm-inline-block d-xs-inline-block d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none">
      <div class="navbar-text">Hello User!</div>
    </div>
    <button id="menuButton" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar" aria-controls="top-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">X</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="link1">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="link2">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="link3">Link3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="navbar-text d-sm-none d-xs-none d-md-inline-block d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block">
        Hello Mr Lebowski!
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="logout" class="nav-link">Log out</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I just don't get it. Have they removed support for `<header>` or `<nav>` in the latest iOs Safari? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems like it has been going on for some time Nick. Weird though. I've never experienced it personally. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627037/bootstrap-4-navbar-dropdown-not-working-on-ios-devices-safari

Comment: Looks like in his case the nav appears but the dropdown does not work. In my case it does not appear at all.