# How to edit the bootstrap.js file of gem twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is definitely wrong, but I cannot seem to get sub menu links to work on mobile devices, and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178606/bootstrap-dropdown-navigation-not-working-on-mobile-browsers) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435359/bootstrap-collapsed-menu-links-not-working-on-mobile-devices/17440942#17440942) suggest edditing the bootstrap.min.js file.

However, since I am using the gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" I do not know where the file is and even if it would work to change it.

Ideas?

This is my code, omitted some parts.

```
<%= nav_bar :fixed => :top, :brand => image_tag('logo.png'), :responsive => true do %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= menu_group :pull => :right do %>
            <%= drop_down "Scan" do %>
                <%= menu_item "Android", 'http://sasfad' %>
                <%= menu_item "iPhone", 'zxing://asfasdf' %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you shouldn't edit those files. But you can fork the gem, edit the bootstrap.min.js file and use your forked gem in your Gemfile.

My recommendation is not to use the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem as the only thing it does is adding for you the assets to the asset pipeline.

Comment: Its not the only thing it does. It generates twitter bootstrap views completely translatable by i18n. I would make a fork and use your branch on Gemfile.

Comment: I am not really that intersted in i18n, however (not that it makes that big of a difference to me now) I would like to be able to use Less. Can I use it (without complication) without the gem? And moreover, in case I give up on it, can I simply remove the line from my gemfile? thanks guys!