# Responsive menu closing when clicked on a Bootstrap v3.3.7 modified template site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, navigation

I am new to Stack Overlow.  I am having some issues with this bootstrap template that I have modified for a work website I am creating. When on mobile, the navigation closes when I try to open one of the submenus.  I am a bit of a newbie to coding so please excuse my ignorance.  I have tried researching this but have come up short with a solution.  The website is http://aventurasecure.com/.  Thanks in advance for any help and again please pardon my newbieness.  The code for the menu is below.

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
       <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="logo-wrapper"
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/Aventura_Logo1.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

<div class="nav-center">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Cameras</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </li>
                <li><a href="#">IP Cameras</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Analog HD Cameras</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Body Worn Cameras</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">ANPR Cameras</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long Range Systems</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="divider"></li>

              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Video Management</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </li>
                <li><a href="#">Network Video Recorders</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Digital Video Recorders (HD)</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">License Plate Recognition (ANPR)</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Encoders/Decoders</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Central Management</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Client Remote Workstation</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Matrix Systems</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Mobile Systems</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Video Storage Servers</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Video Wall Controllers</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Under Vehicle Surveillance</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>


              <li class="divider"></li>

              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Physical Security</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </li>
                <li><a href="#">Access Control</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Intercom & PA Systems</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Ground Based Radar</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Guard Tour Security Systems</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Key Management Systems</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Perimeter Intrusion</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Road Barriers and Bollards</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Turnstiles</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Parking Management</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Perimeter Intrusion (PIDS)</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">XRay Security Scanners</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="divider"></li>

              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Accessories</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </li>
                <li><a href="#">Housings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lenses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Brackets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IR Illuminators</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cables and Connectors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Distribution Amplifiers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Network Systems</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fiber Optics (Analog)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fiber Optics (IP)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wireless Systems</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">UTP Transmission</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IP over Coax</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

                            <li class="divider"></li>

              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Software</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </li>
            <li><a href="#">Video Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Face Recognition</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">License Plate Recognition</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PSIM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Video Analytics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Software Development kits</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>


          </ul>
        </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Markets<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Military</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Law Enforcement</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Homeland Defense</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Critical Infrastructure</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Government</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Industry</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Support<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">DVRs</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cameras & Lenses</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cabling</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Connection Diagrams</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
                </li>
           <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Company Info</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Client List</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        </form></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. It's best to look first if someone had the same problem like you

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435359/bootstrap-collapsed-menu-links-not-working-on-mobile-devices)