# jQuery Mmenu mobile issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mmenu

I'm currently working on a responsive website. I'm using jQuery MMenu for the menu and it's working perfectly in all desktop resolutions expect when I see the website in a smartphone.

The submenu is not displayed correctly. As you can see in the image link below when I open the submenu the last item is part of the first menu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlMoF.png

I don't know why is this happening, have this ever occurred to you?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: When I tried it on my phone I didn't even have the submenu option. It's still hard to get a grasp on what is going wrong though as I don't have the raw nav bar code... Could it potentially be a solution like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178606/bootstrap-dropdown-navigation-not-working-on-mobile-browsers

Comment: @Dacotah you can't see the arrows to open the submenu?

Comment: Sorry I just went back and looked. They are there but way off the screen.

Comment: @Dacotah Weird, in my phone I can see the arrows fine