# Bootstrap collapse button not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to look aroung for a solution to this problem. My web page works great on the desktop, but when I load the file onto my phone for testing the collapse button doesn't funtion. The phone knows that it is a button, but the information behind the button doesn't shoe.

Here is the code for the button.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

I am using the most recent version of bootstrap. Any thoughts?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported all the .js files proparly?
else check this link: [Bootstrap v2 Dropdown Navigation not working on Mobile Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178606/bootstrap-v2-dropdown-navigation-not-working-on-mobile-browsers)

Comment: I am pretty sure that everything is imported correctly. I looked at that link and I have tried what it says, but it still didn't work.

Comment: i have have looked at your problem and if i were you i would try to do what this link says : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse_simple_in&stacked=h

Comment: i hope i help you out