# Menu of Mobile version of web not working on mobile browsers

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code to show a dropdown menu at the right top side of a web.

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-user"></i> 
                                <?php echo $row['userEmail']; ?> <i class="caret"></i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                 <li>
                                        <a href="miperfil.php">Mi perfil</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a  href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

The two options work fine on a desktop PC but they don't respond on a mobile device.
What should I change to have them working on both mobile and desktop browsers?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's hard based on what you have asked to visualize what the problem is.

Comment: @CharlieFish, the problem is that using a mobile device browser the links are not working, and using a desktop PC browser the two links are working

Comment: Like they aren't clickable or they aren't displaying?

Comment: @CharlieFish, I have found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178606/bootstrap-v2-dropdown-navigation-not-working-on-mobile-browsers . Thank you

Comment: No need to post the same comment more then once.

Comment: Thanks for posting solution that resloved your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap v2 Dropdown Navigation not working on Mobile Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178606/bootstrap-v2-dropdown-navigation-not-working-on-mobile-browsers)