# Bootstrap work on computer browser but doesn't work on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap for my site the toggle button work on computer browser but don't work on mobile browser

**This is the code:**

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico"  />

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar4">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.php"><img src="img/t-square-logo-Final.png" alt="T-square" class="tslogo"/></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar4" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="main.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="dms.php">DMS</a></li>
          <li><a href="main.php?action=backup">Backup</a></li>
          <li><a href="logout.php">LogOut</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I try to do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178606/bootstrap-v2-dropdown-navigation-not-working-on-mobile-browsers)
But i stil have the same problem

Any one can help to solve my problem ??

Comment: If you already have the correct meta viewport added then can you post your entire code so we can see exactly what is going on

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 please check above

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 i solve my problem by changing the file bootstrap.min.js to bootstrap.js

Comment: Awesome glad you got it it fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script: bootstrap.min.js is not loaded. When i delete this file in my project the toggle buttons stops working.

Can you verify if your file is loaded properly?

Comment: This. Sometimes a .min file doesn't exist just because IntelliSense gives a suggsetion for it.

Comment: @Xariez And that why i don't use code completion ;)

Comment: @Xariez i solve my problem by changing the file bootstrap.min.js to bootstrap.js

Comment: Got to admit though, it's real handy sometimes ;) Anyhow, glad you got it fixed, should accept this as an answer so we know it's fixed! @mohamadmohamad

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have this code in my header