# HTML + RoR dropdown not clickable on mobile

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, mobile, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

```
      <div class="dropdown pull-right">
        <a id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="true">
          <%= theme_icon_tag "settings" %>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown" style="padding: 0.25em">
          <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_review_path(review.book, review), class: "btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-item" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Delete", book_review_path(review.book, review), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn btn-outline-danger dropdown-item" %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is my dropdown and it's working fine on desktop.
Ive got my phone laying around and wanted to test it's functionality and I realized that I am not able to click the icon to open the dropdown-menu.

Why is that?

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841690/6392696

Comment: Indeed, managed to solve this. Thank you my man. If I could I would give you my upvote!

Comment: I added a new answer please correct the answer if this work for you @flenning12

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you stackoverflow.com/a/17841690/6392696

Find this file  bootstrap.min.js , In substring

```
"ontouchstart"
```

Replace it with

```
"disable-ontouchstart"
```

Hopefully this will help!